# MD5 hash Go to Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, go, hash, md5

I have following code:

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type Payload struct {
    HVIN []byte `json:"hvin"`
}

func main() {
    vin := "1GBJC34R1VF063154"
    md5 := md5.New()
    md5Vin := md5.Sum([]byte(vin))
    payload := &Payload{
        HVIN: md5Vin,
    }
    b, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    fmt.Printf("%s", string(b))

}
```

If I run the code at: https://play.golang.org/ I get following output:

```
{"hvin":"MUdCSkMzNFIxVkYwNjMxNTTUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+"}
```

How can I replicate this in Python 3 ?

I tried following:

```
import hashlib 

result = hashlib.md5(b'1GBJC34R1VF063154')
print(result.hexdigest())
```

Getting following output which doesn't match output given by Go:

```
a40f771ea430ae32dbc5e818387549d3
```

Thank you.

Comment: What do you get if you replace `fmt.Printf("%s", string(b))` with `fmt.Printf("%x", md5Vin)`?

Comment: FYI, the Go output the Base64 encoded input, plus some garbage at the end: piping it onto `base64 -D` prints `1GBJC34R1VF063154` plus some trailing non-printable bytes.

Comment: Problem is that if I take the hash and do the base64 encoding I am getting: YTQwZjc3MWVhNDMwYWUzMmRiYzVlODE4Mzg3NTQ5ZDM which does not match MUdCSkMzNFIxVkYwNjMxNTTUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments in another answer state that the goal is match the Go code, even though the Go code does not compute the hash of the VIN.

Here's python3 code matches the Go code. This code base64 encodes the concatenation of the VIN and the MD5 initial value.

```
vin := "1GBJC34R1VF063154"
b0 = vin.encode('utf-8')
b1 = hashlib.md5(b'').digest()
s =  base64.b64encode(b0 + b1).decode('ascii') // to match Go's encoding/json
print(f'{{"hvin":"{s}"}}')
```

The author of the Go code probably intended to write this:

```
vin := "1GBJC34R1VF063154"
md5Vin := md5.Sum([]byte(vin))
payload := &Payload{
    HVIN: md5Vin[:],
}
b, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
fmt.Printf("%s", string(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the hash incorrectly:

```
    vin := "1GBJC34R1VF063154"
    md5 := md5.New()
    md5.Write([]byte(vin))
    md5Vin := md5.Sum(nil)
    // This should give a40f771ea430ae32dbc5e818387549d3
    fmt.Printf("%x",md5Vin)
    payload := &Payload{
        HVIN: md5Vin,
    }
    b, _ := json.Marshal(payload)
    // This will print the base64-encoded version of the hash
    fmt.Printf("%s", string(b))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but I need to be able to match the output. The base64 encoded version of hash is: YTQwZjc3MWVhNDMwYWUzMmRiYzVlODE4Mzg3NTQ5ZDM which does not match MUdCSkMzNFIxVkYwNjMxNTTUHYzZjwCyBOmACZjs+EJ+

Comment: Your go program output is wrong, do not try to match it with python. The base64 output should be YTQw... not MUdC...

Comment: You are using `md5.Sum` incorrectly. Check my code. You're missing `md5.Write` in your code. Your program output is not the base64 encoding of the hash, it is the base64 encoding of VIN+binarydata

Comment: Problem is that I unfortunately cannot affect that, even thou it's not correct using of hash as you say, that's how program I am dependent on works and I can't affect that, can you please explain VIN+binarydata ? Binary data of hash ? Maybe I can concat that together and encode64 to get desired format ?

Comment: Read the documentation for `hash.Sum()`. You are not computing the hash by calling `md5.Sum(vin)`. You are appending the current hash value in `md5`  to `vin`. Since you just created md5, it is initialized with the md5 initialization vector. So the output is VIN+md5 initialization vector. You are simply appending a constant binary value to whatever VIN you have. If you want to emulate the broken hash in python, then get the hash of a 0-length input, concatenate that binary hash to the VIN, and base64 that. But that's just wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you just have to follow the examples from https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/md5/#example_New

Golang

```
package main

import (
    "crypto/md5"
    "fmt"
    "io"
)

func main() {
    h := md5.New()
    vin := "1GBJC34R1VF063154"
    io.WriteString(h, vin)
    fmt.Printf("%x", h.Sum(nil)) // a40f771ea430ae32dbc5e818387549d3
}
```

Python

```
Python 3.6.8 (default, Oct  7 2019, 12:59:55) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import hashlib 
>>> 
>>> result = hashlib.md5(b'1GBJC34R1VF063154')
>>> print(result.hexdigest()) 
a40f771ea430ae32dbc5e818387549d3
```

Golang's `%x` in `fmt` prints "... base 16, with lower-case letters for a-f". 
More: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/